# How To Package Executable Terminal Commands

Tags: command-line

Let's say I have a downloadable text file on my website that says

```
sudo apt-getupdate
```

How can I make it so that the user downloads it and it auto puts that code into terminal? What would I do for something that has many lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the beginning of the text file, Ubuntu will know than is an executable file to be interpreted by bash. So your file would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
```

When the user double clicks the file, she/he will be asked if wants the executable to be run in a terminal.

Comment: This wont work all this time. First, the file has to be set to executable, then the appropriate setting needs to be set in Files -> Preferences -> Behaviour -> Executable Text Files.

Comment: Yes, I was asuming that behaviour, but you're right. I've upvoted your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply give your user these commands:

```
wget -O- http://example.com/script.sh | bash -
```

You will need to replace `bash` with the program which should execute your script.

---

The first method will **not** save the file on disk. It will only be downloaded and directly executed. If the file should be saved, you can use the following:

```
wget http://example.com/script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

The file will be kept as `script.sh` in the current directory. This requires a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top of the file.